# Integral dx term sanity check

Tags: calculus, integration

In my lecture slides, the dx term occasionally precedes the function being integrated. I understand that dx means "an infinitely small width of x" but does the definition of integration require it to be the final term?

My question really is:

Does the following equality hold?

$\int (f(x)~dx) = \int (dxf(x))  $

Comment: Yes, those two expressions are equal.

Comment: I would say that they are not equal, but maybe are intended to be. The left hand side is the integral of $f(x)$ whereas the right side is $(x+c)\cdot f(x)$. I would say it is improper notation.

Comment: I'm not sure in what areas of mathematics it is common to place $dx$ in front of the function (I have not seen it used by mathematicians myself), but this is a common way of writing integrals by physicists. Are you being taught by someone who works in mathematical physics?

Comment: @KCd It came up in my machine learning course when computing marginal likelihoods. $p(D|m) = \int
dθ p(D|θ, m)p(θ|m)$ where θ is the model parameters, D is the data and m is the model.

Comment: Maybe the instructor is an ex-physicist. Let's see if others can comment on whether such a notational convention is common in statistics.

Comment: This is just a matter of notation, thus it might be inappropriate to call it an "equality". It is sometimes convenient to have the $dx$ up front, but really should be nothing more than that: notation. If $A$ and $B$ both represent the same, notationally, then we write $A=B$, but the $=$ here carries another meaning, as opposed to say, $1+1=2$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes indeed: $$\int f(x)~dx = \int dx\,f(x)~$$ Both sides of the equation "say" precisely the same thing.

We just want $\,dx$ to appear ***in*** the integrand, as it indicates the variable with respect to which we are integrating.  Whether $dx$ appears before, or after, the rest the integrand, simply doesn't matter.

I always prefer, for example, when a sum appears as the integral, or a product, to enclose it all in parentheses:

$$\int \left(f(x)~dx\right) = \int \left(dx\,f(x)\right)$$ particularly if the right hand side appears (as is often done in physics texts, or areas of applied math), to ensure it's not misinterpreted to be $\displaystyle \left(\int dx\right)f(x)$, which is something altogether different.

Comment: Looks sane to me! :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

You can read (as a heuristic) $\displaystyle \int f(x)\,dx$ as the sum of the products of $f(x)$ by the width $dx$. These are 'real numbers' so commute, so yes they mean the same thing.